# How can you test if a page can be anonymously accessible within an app you have already authenticated in?

Tags: manual-testing, testcase, web-application, security-testing, web

I am trying to ensure that a page that can be visited from within an app that requires user to be logged in, can be accessed anonymously. A controller has been introduced that can present views as static pages and want to ensure that the targeted page is anonymously accessible. Is there a way to verify that using Fiddler or network tab? Basically want to make sure that there is no details that can trace back to the logged in session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few options here on how to test a page that should be viewable without authenticating.

1. Use a different browser. If you're logged in via Chrome, can you access the static page in Firefox (not logged in)? Browser's cookies do not transfer between different browsers (if your app is using cookies).
2. Use the browser's incognito/private browsing mode. Like number 1, incognito mode doesn't view cookies, so regardless if you are logged into the site, can you access the static page?
3. Have access to VPN? You can try accessing the static page via a VPN service.

Comment: Thanks Lee, is there anything in network tab or using fiddler that would confirm it's an 'anonymous' session?

Comment: The network Tab shows you the transferred headers and cookies, if no session token is in there you're anonymous. But this needs some manual checking with knowledge of your domain since the DevTools can not know which tokens your application uses to define a session.

Comment: Yes, @Daniel is right! The network tab can be used to verify the existence of auth tokens. I don't think you need to use Fiddler for this. There's no need to intercept network traffic for this test.

Comment: You're welcome @metavaronos. If you like this answer, feel free to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks Lee will do, and thanks @Daniel as well.